# Joomla 3: how to add text inside html tag via php or native joomla API? (no js or JQ)

Tags: php, joomla

He there

Is there any way to add some text inside html tag in joomla3 per webpage?

```
<html>


</html>
```

to

```
<html 'some text' >

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside the `index.php` file of the template. Templates are located in the `templates` directory. For example for the default *protostar* template (located in `templates/protostar`) you can find the `<html>` tag in line 83 [here](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/templates/protostar/index.php). Any change you do on a template will reflect to the pages that this template is assigned to.

Comment: I knew that...it is just an edit. I wana do that via php. becuase each pages has different text in html tag.

Comment: You would use a system plugin probably and have it set the value of `$text` based on context.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding 'some text' will invalidate your html. You should add any custom hooks you need as a class on that element, exactly as is already done on the body class;

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/templates/protostar/index.php#L136